# std::transform unary operation signature

Tags: c++, stl

I'm puzzled with the following [description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) of std::transfrom:

> **unary_op** - unary operation function object that will be applied. 
>   The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> `Ret fun(const Type &a);`
>
> The signature does not need to have `const &`.

These two statements seem contradictory. Could someone clarify what is meant here? What happens if signature is `Ret fun(Type a)` or `Ret fun(Type&& a)` or `Ret fun(Type& a)`?

Comment: I think the question is too broad.

Comment: For example for arithmetic types that is for simple types there is no great advantage to use const int & instead of int.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, My question is not about what is better. It's about how the function work, and why documentation first says that signature has to have `const&` and the very next statement that is doesn't have to have it.

Comment: I did not see the verb "has to have". I see the verb "should".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The question is still not trying to ask "what is best", but "what are the actual requirements", and that seems to me to be a good question.

Comment: "should be equivalent to" != "has to have"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it is trying to say, is that `fun` must be such that:

```
*OutputIt = fun(*InputIt);
```

is legal.  Note also that

> `unary_op` ... must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, or modify any elements of the ranges involved.

, so a non-const reference would be legal - but it mustn't *use* the non-constness.